# Error handling system.outofmemoryexception

Tags: c#

I am using multithreading to post content to 1 url. My error is that when I run 300 threads, after 10 to 15 minutes, I will be pushed out and get the message "system.outofmemoryexception". According to my attention, the configuration of my computer is: Ram 32G, 12 Core, 24 Threads ...! I'm new so I don't know how to handle it. Can you help me? I would like to thank anyway.

Code:

```
int sothread = 100; 
for (int ii = 0; ii < sothread; ii++) 
    Thread t2 = new Thread(() => { 
        while (true) {
            string url = "https://phamnhi.net"; 
            string data = "id=123213&view=333"; 
            html = PostData(http, url, data, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8").ToString(); 
            try { 
                if (html.Contains("OK")) { 
                    row.Cells[status].Value = "ok..."; 
                    Thread.Sleep(20000); 
                    http.Close(); 
                }
            } catch (OverflowException) { break; } 
        } 
    });
     t.IsBackground = true;
     t.Start();
     Thread.Sleep(1000); 
}
```

Comment: whats in `PostData`?

Comment: Why the http.Close after 20 seconds? (The Sleep(20000) = 20 seconds.) Seems to me you should close http somewhere outside these loops, when they're all done. Keep in mind that this happens inside an infinite loop out of 100 loops.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to release the resources of your program after they execute. If every thread spins up more work without coming to completion, you're going to run out of memory eventually. 
Please post some of the code for analysis.

Comment: `int sothread = 100;
 for (int ii = 0; ii < sothread; ii++)                             
Thread t2 = new Thread(() =>
{       
while (true)
{
string url = "https://phamnhi.net";
string data = "id=123213&view=333";
 html = PostData(http, url, data, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8").ToString();
 try
{
if (html.Contains("OK"))
{
row.Cells[status].Value = "ok...";
Thread.Sleep(20000);
http.Close();
 }
 }
catch (OverflowException)
{
break;
}
}
});
 t.IsBackground = true;
 t.Start();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
} `

Comment: @Navila: Edit your code into the question. Do not post it in a comment!

Comment: I edited the post to include the code from the comment.